# Random Walk on Clock Hands

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains, random-walk, uniform-distribution

We do a random walk on a clock. Each step the hour hand moves clockwise or counterclockwise each with probability 1/2 independently of previous steps.

If you start at 1 what is the expected number before you hit 12?

Well, the answer is 11 according to the simulations I ran. I know to return to 1, or from any number back to itself, it would be 12 because of the properties of the invariant distribution; so if you start at a certain position in the long run you can expect to come back once every 12 times. The invariant distribution is uniform across the 12 states. I can't explain it beyond that case though. I got ~20 steps on average to get the hands to move from 1 to 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not problems on a circle but on the linear interval of integers $$L=\{0,1,2,\ldots,12\},$$ where the hand $12$ is represented by both states $0$ and $12$, and every other hand by the state with its number. Starting from $k$ in $L$, the mean number of steps $t_k$ that the symmetric simple random walk needs to hit $0$ or $12$ is $$t_k=k(12-k),$$ hence your simulations giving $t_1=11$ and $t_2=20$ (since hitting $11$ starting from $1$ on the clock is equivalent to hitting $12$ starting from $2$) are accurate.

To show this, the standard method is to consider the whole collection $(t_k)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant12}$ simultaneously. Then, $$t_0=t_{12}=0,$$ and the (simple) Markov property of the random walk after one step yields $$t_k=1+\tfrac12(t_{k-1}+t_{k+1}),$$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant11$. Solving this $13\times13$ affine system yields the desired formula.

Answer (score -2):

```
from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from __future__ import division
% matplotlib inline
r=12
lt=[0]*r
x,y=[],[]
count,pos=0,0
flag=False
n=10000
lc=[]
for i in range(n):
    while not flag:
        count+=1
        if random()<.5:
            pos+=1
        else:
            pos+=-1
        pos%=r
        lt[pos]=1
        if sum(lt)==12:
            flag=True
            lc.append(count)
            count=0
    flag=False
    lt=[0]*r
    pos=0
plt.plot(lc)
print np.average(lc)
```

~67.04525 as far as I found

How: I just built an array of 12 0's and a random variable uniformly distributed and I just defined when this variable is less than .5 it steps clockwise  one position or else the  other way around. (turning 0 in the n-position into 1)

Counting the number of steps it took for all the 0's to become 1 and repeating this 10000 times y arrived that result.

Feel free to run this code at jupyter notebook online

Comment: For those of us that don't read Python(?), an explanation of what your code is doing (and why that is the right thing to do) would be helpful.  Remember that in mathematics, the right answer is not nearly as important as a clear explanation of where that answer came from, ideally presented in a way that might allow for generalization.