# A random walk on the clock

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

The setting is simple but I just don't know how to calculate a desired quantity, which will be introduced later.

---

Suppose we have a clock with $M$ points on it, i.e. $\{0, 1, 2, ..., M-1\}$, where $M\in\mathbb N$.

Suppose we starts at some point on the clock, say $a$, where $0\leq a\leq M-1$.

We have a probability of $1/2$ to stay at point $a$, and a probability of $1/2$ to move. If we move, then we will have a probability $p$ to move clockwise and a probability $1-p$ to move anti-clockwise, where $0<p<1$.

Let $X_n$ denote our location after $n$ steps. We define $d(x)=\min\{x,M-x\}$  for all $0\leq x \leq M-1$, i.e. the distance between $x$ and the point $0$.

---

**Question:** Calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb E[d(X_n)]$, where $\mathbb E$ means expectation.

I have been thinking this problem for quite a while but don't know how to approach it. We cannot use the same argument as [in this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047259/random-walk-on-clock-hands) (cf. @Did 's post in the answer) because $\mathbb E[d(X_n)|X_0=y]$ may be different for different $y$, where $0\leq y \leq M-1$. That's, our problem doesn't have "symmetry".

Also, I don't know if we need to consider $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb E[d(X_n)]$ as a whole or consider the limit and the expectation separately, which means first calculating the expectation and then taking limit.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Existence of a Stationary Distribution**

First note that the Markov chain you describe is on a finite state space, it is aperiodic, and irreducible.

As a result we can use the convergence theorem for Markov chains (eg. Theorem 4.9 In [Levin and Peres](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf)), which states that a unique stationary distribution for the chain exists, and in the limit the time spent in each state is given by the stationary distribution.

**Identifying the Stationary Distribution**

In general, if a stationary distribution, $\pi$, exists (which in our case from above we know it does) satisfies the equation

$$\pi = \pi P$$

(Definition 1.5.1 in Levin and Peres).

For your Markov chain, it is a relatively straightforward matrix calculation to show that the stationary distribution is

$$\pi = \left(\frac1M, \ldots, \frac1M\right)$$

So in the limit the probability the Markov chain is in any given state is uniform:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbf P[X_n = m | X_0 = a] = \frac1M$$

**Exchanging Order of Limits/Expectations**

Because the Markov chain has a finite state space, you are safe to exchange the order of limits and expectations (formally this is the [Bounded Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Bounded_convergence_theorem), which in turn is a simple case of the Dominated Convergence Theorem). Combining this with the [Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbf E[d(X_n)] & = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} d(m) \mathbf P[X_n = m] \\
& =  \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} d(m) \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbf P[X_n = m]
\\
& = \frac1M \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} d(m)
\end{align*} 
$$

**Evaluating the Sum**

Finally it remains to evaluate the sum over $d(m)$. Letting $D(M) = \sum_{m=0}^{M-1}d(m)$, then from examining some cases for small $M$ one can see that $D(M)$ satisfies the recurrence relation

$$D(M) = D(M-1) + \Bigl\lfloor\frac{M}{2} \Bigr\rfloor,$$

which for $M = 1,\cdots, 6$ is $0,1,2,4,6,9,12$. Checking the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+6%2C+9%2C+12&language=english&go=Search), this sequence is known as the *quarter squares* and has the closed form:

$$D(M) = \Bigl\lfloor\frac{M^2}{4} \Bigr\rfloor$$

From which we have

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbf E[d(X_n)] = \frac1M \Bigl\lfloor\frac{M^2}{4} \Bigr\rfloor.$$

Comment: Thanks for the post!!! Just one more quick question. The stationary distribution from the theorem is also unique, right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes - for an irreducible Markov chain, existence of a stationary distribution also implies uniqueness.

Comment: Sorry, I had one more final quick question… The equality that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbf P[X_n = m | X_0 = a] = \frac1M$ holds for all $a\in \mathbb Z/ M\mathbb Z$ (because the argument applies for all $a$ and we have uniqueness of the limiting distribution), right? Thanks…

Comment: Yes - the stationary distribution of a Markov chain doesn't depend on the initial state. The heuristic is that if you *mix* a Markov chain enough it doesn't matter where you start from.